# separate file uploads node.js

Tags: html, node.js, multer

I want to know the easiest way to handle two separate file uploads, one for images and the other for audio. right now I am using multer and it uploads all multipart uploads to the same location.  can I specify different locations for both file uploads?

Comment: Check out [`.rename()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#rename-fieldname-filename-req-res).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to save the files to disk, you can do something like this:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        if (file.fieldname === 'image-file') {
            return cb(null, 'folder-for-image-uploads');
        }

        if (file.fieldname === 'audio-file') {
            return cb(null, 'folder-for-audio-uploads');
        }

        cb(new Error('Unknown fieldname: ' + file.fieldname));
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        if (file.fieldname === 'image-file') {
            return cb(null, 'image-filename.jpg');
        }

        if (file.fieldname === 'audio-file') {
            return cb(null, 'audio-filename.mp3');
        }

        cb(new Error('Unknown fieldname: ' + file.fieldname));
    }
});

var upload = multer({storage: storage});

app.post('/endpoint', upload.fields([{name: 'image-file', maxCount: 1}, {name: 'audio-file', maxCount: 1}]), function(req, res) {
    // handle request, files already saved to disk
    res.sendStatus(200);
}
```

For this to work, you need the name of `input` HTML elements to match the `fieldname` property, e.g.:

```
<form method="POST" action="/endpoint" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image-file">
    <input type="file" name="audio-file">
    <input type="submit">Submit</input>
</form>
```